# react can't compile its own JSX syntax

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
./src/pages/profile/Profile.jsx
Syntax error: Unexpected token (24:5)

  22 | 
  23 |   return (
> 24 |     <>
     |      ^
  25 |       <Topbar />
  26 |       <div className="profile">
  27 |         <Sidebar />
```

```
<>
...
</>
```

The above is in fact valid JSX syntax, so why can't it giving me a compilation error?

Comment: What version of react?

Comment: What does your build pipeline look like?

Answer (score 0):

React has Fragment support since version `16.2`.

[React v16.2.0: Improved Support for Fragments](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#jsx-fragment-syntax)

so you have an old version of `react` and an old version of `react-scripts`.
Please update them to latest versions (e.g. `16.13` if you don't want to move to version 17) and react-scripts to `4.0.3` and try again.